# django 1.2 tutorials, books and resources?

Tags: django, resources

Where can I find learning resources for django 1.2? I'm new to django and web-programming.

Comment: http://www.djangobook.com/ is THE BEST book. Hands down. I'm was a PHP programmer. I never wanted to learn django. But after few years, here I am searching for good book on django. I just wanted to give it a try. I watched some screencasts on show me do and other video tutorials on youtube. I started hated django. It looked too complex to me. I didn't understand why people where doing this and that while writing django apps. Finally yesterday I turned to djangobook.com as my last resort. I finished 5 chapters. Now, I LOVE django. Its awesome. The book is awesome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have started to learn django a couple of months ago so, I'll try to point out what helped me.

I started watching the series of screencasts on how to build a wiki
http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=1100000
which is pretty easy. If you like watching screencasts they're not bad.

The [official tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial01/) as pointed out before is also good.

I then progressed reading [the online book on django](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/). While it is certainly a good reference, I wouldn't recommend it as a starting point though.

I think a better thing to do is to read the [practical django projects](http://rcm.amazon.com/e/cm?lt1=_blank&bc1=000000&IS2=1&bg1=FFFFFF&fc1=000000&lc1=0000FF&t=paublo0a-20&o=1&p=8&l=as4&m=amazon&f=ifr&asins=1430219386) book by James Benett, the django release manager. It shows you a bunch of best practices which you might overlook (I did) otherwise. It uses django 1.1 but I think most of the code works (sometimes critized in reviews on amazon).

One thing that escaped me for a while is the wealth of third-party django apps which really make your life a lot easier but are not *official* so they are usually not in *official* supporting documentation (all of the above).

I recommend you start using

- [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) (for database changes)

immediately. Also consider start using

- [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and
- [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) (both for python package management)

right away. These facilitate package-management *a lot* and I think using these is considered best practices (I just had to clean up a easy_install-foobar'ed system and it's no fun). If you are interested in the best third-party apps for solving common problems in django check out the blog [surfing in Kansas](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2009/nov/6/large-problems-database-migrations/) by django developer Eric Holscher. There is also [a video](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2010/sep/10/djangocon-talk/) from the recent djangocon.

Finally, if you are like me and wondering about the *magic* that django does, you might want to check out [this blog post](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/13/how-django-processes-request/) or [this video (3hrs)](http://pycon.blip.tv/file/3322277/) (and [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/ubernostrum/django-in-depth)) by James Bennett explaining the internals of django very well (I like the blog post better, but take your pick).

Also: I was unaware of the [django-users mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users), this is very helpful and - as far as django is concerned - much more active than stackoverflow.

Django is awesome! I really hope you like it ;)

Answer (score 2):

What about the official tutorial?

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 1):

The online documentation is pretty good. And there's a tutorial for beginners.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/

Answer (score 1):

This resource http://www.udemy.com/full-django-tutorial/ at Udemy can be good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the djangobook covering the 1.x.x versions. http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/ That can be a good start.